# Cutting up a human face for links

Tags: jquery, css, image, html

So I'm trying to use a face as sort of a navigation tool in jQuery/css/html page. Is the best way to do this is by cutting up each element like the eyes the nose and the mouth and than align them using square divs on html? I feel that no matter how much I try it's not going to end up properly aligned? anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you could use an image map : http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp

**EDIT** As Nick points out in the comments, you can have circle shapes as well. Best option for heads and eyes etc

Comment: You must be a sitepoint podcast listener as well :D - The examples area seems to be broken however.

Comment: You can use circle shapes in image maps

Comment: @Nick, thanks for that! I should start paying attention to my own links from now on!

Answer (score 2):

I would leave the image fully intact as a single background image and position invisible `<a>` tags over the proper locations to act as links

Comment: I thought of that but Each element has to become separated once a user clicks on it.  I have it right now with blocks animating using jQuery to different areas of the page.  Once you click one the other 4 fade away.  Just thinking  but if I were to do that do you know if it's possible that i can have the background element fade out and load up the precut up eye image i have?

Answer (score 1):

I would not use CSS sprites here but leave it as a single image and overlay each "hot-spots" with anchor tags or the like. However CSS sprites are really cool and in other similar scenario's may be the best solution.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Comment: Thanks css seems like the most realistic approach to go about this I'm just worried about implementing the jQuery movement and fade out. I'll let you know how it all goes thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

Do it as SVG? You could still use javascript to manipulate the location of parts of the SVG document.

Comment: SVG is just xml. If you cut your face into sub-images, then you can embed it in the SVG (use a tool, it will be base-64 encoded), and locate each of the sub-images on the SVG "canvas". When resized, the whole thing will scale (and your images will be resampled, but should remain correctly aligned).